# Is it possible for the Android WebView to announce only it's content in TalkBack?

Tags: android, webview, accessibility, talkback

When using TalkBack and iterating over the screen and the next element is a WebView, the first thing what TalkBack announces is the WebView itself, which is not really informative. After I swipe again, the TalkBack starts to iterate over the content of the page in the WebView.

What I want to achieve is that the Talkback jumps straight to the content of the WebView instead of announcing that it's a WebView. Is it even possible? I couldn't find any option for that. Or is this considered a bad practice?

Comment: I'm afraid no, I found a similar question with answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039308/android-skip-focus-of-webview-and-go-straight-to-content-with-talkback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Skip Focus of WebView and Go Straight To Content with TalkBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039308/android-skip-focus-of-webview-and-go-straight-to-content-with-talkback)