# Is there a way to change the text announced by TalkBack (Accessibility) for a WebView in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility

Seems like no matter what I do, Android will announce "WebView" (seems like this may be intentional)

I'm not super familiar with accessibility delegates so I may have missed a potential solution in there but I want to change the announcement to be something more descriptive rather than just "WebView"

I've tried:

1. Setting the content description
2. Changing accessibility pane titles
3. Overriding accessibility delegate
4. Sending a custom talkback event when focus is gained by the view (but this only works if we delay it and in that case it will only announce after webview is announced)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Skip Focus of WebView and Go Straight To Content with TalkBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039308/android-skip-focus-of-webview-and-go-straight-to-content-with-talkback)

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon Not really, I'm not looking to skip the WebView, just announce a different name